# Linux regex not working with AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

Below regex not working, could you please help to fix the same.

Below is my linux system flavour :

```
Linux VMIUAT01.ttsl.com 2.6.18-419.0.0.0.2.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jun 28 20:18:51 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For case1 and case 2 have entered correct text, but still getting error response.

For case3 have entered wrong text, but getting no error response

case 1:
code

```
echo "TT07PMTP0600" | gawk '{if ($1 !~ /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/) {print "Error 203: Unique Record ID No contains Non Alphanumeric values,Field position 3, Linenumber:"NR,$0}}'
```

output : have entered correct text, but still getting error response.

```
Error 203: Unique Record ID No contains Non Alphanumeric values,Field position 3, Linenumber:1 TT07PMTP0600
```

case 2:

code

```
echo "22-Jun-18" | awk '{if ($1 !~ /^[0-9]{2}\-[A-Za-z]{3}\-[1-9]{2}$/) {print "Error 213: Date of Reporting contains Non Alphanumeric values,Field position 13, Linenumber:"NR,$0}}'
```

output : have entered correct text, but still getting error response.

```
Error 213: Date of Reporting contains Non Alphanumeric values,Field position 13, Linenumber:1 22-Jun-18
```

case 3:

Code

```
echo "product stv," | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/) {print "Error 201: Tariff Product DataType contains Non Alphanumeric values,Field position 1, Linenumber:"NR,$0}}'
```

Output : have entered wrong text, but getting no error response

```
No result, no error thrown
```

Comment: Don't throw in an X-Y problem, stating why your efforts to a problem didn't work. Rather state the problem with a concise testable input and expected output

Comment: I can't reproduce your errors (added an `echo` to the front of case 1).  The case 3 will match because `awk` splits on whitespace and so `$1` is only "product", it does not include the comma.  Even if you used `$0` then the *whole* text has to be wrong, not just one character.

Comment: @as7951, please post 3 simple things in your post, 1st: Sample Input 2nd: sample output and 3rd: what have yo tried so far to solve this problem in code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using [*interval expressions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Operators) for your regular expressions. Depending on the version of `gawk` your are using, you should make use of the flag `--re-interval` The [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Operators) states :

> Interval expressions were not traditionally available in awk. They
>   were added as part of the POSIX standard to make awk and egrep
>   consistent with each other.
>
> Initially, because old programs may use ‘`{`’ and ‘`}`’ in regexp
>   constants, gawk did not match interval expressions in regexps.
>
> However, ***beginning with version 4.0***, gawk does match interval
>   expressions by default. This is because compatibility with POSIX has
>   become more important to most gawk users than compatibility with old
>   programs.

So, if you have an older version (check with `awk --version`) it is advised to add `--re-interval`. If you use `--posix` you will disable all GNU extension which could come in handy.

> **`man awk` (version 3.1.7):**
>   `--re-interval` Enable the use of interval expressions in regular expression matching (see Regular Expressions, below).  Interval expressions were not traditionally available in the AWK language.  The POSIX standard added them, to make awk and egrep consistent with each other.  However, their use is likely to break old AWK programs, so gawk only provides them if they are requested with this option, or when `--posix` is specified.

- *Case 1* and *Case 2*: (version < 4.0) :

  ```
  $ echo "TT07" | gawk '/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/{print "match";exit}{print "no match"}'
  no match
  $ echo "TT07" | gawk --re-interval '/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/{print "match";exit}{print "no match"}'
  match
  ```
- *Case 1* and *Case 2*: (version ≥ 4.0) :

  ```
  $ echo "TT07" | gawk '/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}/{print "match";exit}{print "no match"}'
  match
  ```
- *Case 3*: this is a completly different issue and nicely explained in the comments by [cdrake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017492/linux-regex-not-working-with-awk#comment89028036_51017492).

  > The case 3 will match because awk splits on whitespace and so `$1` is only "product", it does not include the comma. Even if you used `$0` then the *whole* text has to be wrong, not just one character.

Comment: To be clear - don't use `--posix` for this as it not only enables RE intervals but also disables all gawk extensions, e.g. gensub(). To enable RE intervals in a very old version of gawk just use `--re-interval` or, far better, get a newer version of gawk. And of course, depending on requirements, the right way to write that script is probably `awk '/[[:upper:]]{2}[0-9]{2}/{f=1;exit} END{print (f ? "" : "no ") "match"}'`

Comment: @EdMorton you are totally right. I did not want to complicate the example too much.